# How to show Ads after every time player lose in unity

Tags: javascript, c#, unity-game-engine, admob

I am new to unity ; I just want to test something on a code source so I hired a freelancer to implement ads The ads are showing after 3 times player lose and in the pause menu , I want to show it every time the player loses , can you please show me how to do it and be specific since I am new to all this

here is my ads control

I would really appreciate your help

best regrads

```js
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class UIManager : MonoBehaviour
{

 public GameObject maskPanel, pausePanel, retrievePanel, gameOverPanel, levelClearPanel;

 public Text timerText, coinValueText;

 public float timeMax;

 private float currentTimer;

 public GameObject[] heart;

 public int coinToRetrieve;

 public Sprite[] starSpr;

 public Image starImg;

 public Text coinResultValue;

 void Awake ()
 {
  GameManager._UIManager = this;
 }
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start ()
 {
  currentTimer = timeMax;
  coinValueText.text = GameManager._gotCoin.ToString ();
  AudioManager.Instance.mainMusic.mute = false;
 }
 
 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update ()
 {

  if (Mathf.CeilToInt (currentTimer) > 0) {
   currentTimer -= Time.deltaTime;
   timerText.text = Mathf.CeilToInt (currentTimer).ToString ();
  }
  if (Mathf.CeilToInt (currentTimer) == 0) {

   if (!GameManager.isGameOver) {
    AudioManager.Instance.PlayOutOfTime ();
    GameManager.isGameOver = true;
    StartCoroutine (GameOver ());
   }
  }
  coinValueText.text = GameManager._gotCoin.ToString ();

 }

 public void Pause ()
 {
  AdsControl.Instance.showAds ();
  Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
  maskPanel.SetActive (true);
  pausePanel.SetActive (true);

 }

 public void Resume ()
 {
  Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
  maskPanel.SetActive (false);
  pausePanel.SetActive (false);
 }

 public void Replay ()
 {
  Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
  Application.LoadLevel ("Game");
 }

 public void Back ()
 {
  Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
  Application.LoadLevel ("Home");
 }

 public IEnumerator GameOver ()
 {
  yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.0f);
  AdsControl.Instance.showAds ();
  //int _coin = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Coin");
  if (GameManager._gotCoin >= coinToRetrieve) {
   ShowRetrieve ();
  } else {

   ShowGameOver ();
  }
 }

 void ShowRetrieve ()
 {
  Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
  maskPanel.SetActive (true);
  retrievePanel.SetActive (true);
 }

 public void ShowGameOver ()
 {
  Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
  maskPanel.SetActive (true);
  retrievePanel.SetActive (false);
  gameOverPanel.SetActive (true);
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Coin", GameManager._gotCoin); 
 }

 public void LevelClear ()
 {
  StartCoroutine (LevelClearIE ());
 }

 IEnumerator LevelClearIE ()
 {
  yield return new WaitForSeconds (1.0f);
  Time.timeScale = 0.0f;
  maskPanel.SetActive (true);
  levelClearPanel.SetActive (true);
  int star = 0;
  if (currentTimer >= 0.75f * timeMax) {
   star = 3;
   starImg.sprite = starSpr [2];
  } else if (currentTimer >= 0.5f * timeMax && currentTimer < 0.75f * timeMax) {
   star = 2;
   starImg.sprite = starSpr [1];
  } else {
   star = 1;
   starImg.sprite = starSpr [0];
  }
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Star" + PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CurrentLevel").ToString (), star);
  int currentLevel = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("CurrentLevel");
  int levelActive = PlayerPrefs.GetInt ("Level");
  if (currentLevel == levelActive) {

   currentLevel++;
   PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Level", currentLevel);
   PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("CurrentLevel", currentLevel);
  }
  PlayerPrefs.SetInt ("Coin", GameManager._gotCoin); 
  coinResultValue.text = GameManager._gotCoin.ToString ();
 }

 public void Retrieve ()
 {
  AudioManager.Instance.mainMusic.mute = false;
  GameManager._heart++;
  SetHeart (GameManager._heart);
  GameManager._gotCoin -= coinToRetrieve;
  Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
  maskPanel.SetActive (false);
  retrievePanel.SetActive (false);
  LevelManager.Instance.SpawnPlayer ();
 }

 public void QuitToHome ()
 {
  Time.timeScale = 1.0f;
  Application.LoadLevel ("Home");
 }

 public void NextLevel()
 {
  Application.LoadLevel ("Game");
 }


 public void SetHeart (int _heart)
 {
  if (_heart == 3) {
   heart [2].SetActive (true);
   heart [1].SetActive (true);
   heart [0].SetActive (true);
  } else if (_heart == 2) {
   heart [2].SetActive (false);
   heart [1].SetActive (true);
   heart [0].SetActive (true);
  } else if (_heart == 1) {
   heart [2].SetActive (false);
   heart [1].SetActive (false);
   heart [0].SetActive (true);
  } else {
   heart [2].SetActive (false);
   heart [1].SetActive (false);
   heart [0].SetActive (false);
  }
 }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like ads are being shown after the player looses three hearts. In your above script, the number of hearts a player receives is currently being set by the GameManager script. You can confirm this by changing...

```
SetHeart (GameManager._heart);
```

...in the above script to:

```
SetHeart (1);
```

I'm assuming that the GameManager script sets the number of hearts to 3. This is just a temporary solution to test if your ads will be shown after loosing the game just once.

Can you update the question to include the GameManager script? You should be able to find the script by searching your project for a script with `public class GameManager` near the top of script.

Comment: i updated my Question with the orrect script can you please show me how to do it

Answer (score -1):

I don't know if you're **still** hunting the answer but first you're showing ads at **pause** too with the AdsControl singleton.(go with it if that's what you want but you haven't mentioned it in the question).

```
AdsControl.Instance.showAds();
```

You already are doing this every game over if you haven't any hidden code that coroutine runs every time it's game over